# SwiftUI: align one child view differently from others in a VStack

Tags: swiftui

I have a a `VStack` with child views including an `HStack` with 1 Text and 1 Button. How can I make the `HStack` be aligned to center horizontally on the screen, and all the other views have the `VStack` alignment?

You can see in [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8bkr.png) and the code below, that all child views have the leading alignment:

```
    @State private var email: String = ""
    @State private var password: String = ""
    
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 30) {
            
            Text("Create account")
            TextField("Email", text: $email)
                .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
            TextField("Password", text: $password)
                .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
            Button("Create Account") {
                print("Create account now")
            }
                
            HStack {
                Text("Already have an account? ")
                    
                Button("Login") {
                }
            }
            Spacer()
        }.padding(20)
    }
```

I tried adding some padding like one solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71038584/how-to-align-text-views-differently-under-a-vstack-in-swiftui) but still the `HStack` (the one with "Already have an account? Login") is not completely centered horizontally. You can see in [this iPhone 11 image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOb6V.png) and [this iPod Touch 7 image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ulzM9.png).

```
HStack {
    Text("Already have an account? ")   
    Button("Login") {
    }
}
.padding(.horizontal, 50)
```

Comment: Put the HStack in another VStack with center alignment. 

Comment: Oh right, that also works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two easy ways to achieve this:

```
@State private var email: String = ""
@State private var password: String = ""

var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 30) {
        
        Text("Create account")
        TextField("Email", text: $email)
            .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
        TextField("Password", text: $password)
            .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
        Button("Create Account") {
            print("Create account now")
        }
            
        HStack {
            Spacer() // Either use spacers
            Text("Already have an account? ")
                
            Button("Login") {
            }
            Spacer() // Either use spacers
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center) // Or use a frame
        Spacer()
    }.padding(20)
}
```

You can either put `Spacer()` on either side of the `Text` and `Button` inside the `HStack`, or put a `.frame` on the `HStack` with an infinite width and the correct alignment. Don't use both. During the SwiftUI winter labs, the SwiftUI team was pretty agnostic about either one.

Comment: Just wrap the HStack in a VStack with centre alignment. ‍♂️

Comment: Thanks @Yrb, I ended up using `.frame`